# Share objects among python subprocesses

Tags: python, object, subprocess

I'm actually working on a Python script in which I have a list of dictionaries and then I use a subprocess to run another Python script.

In such second script I need to access the same list of dictionaries present in the first one, so until now I have been doing the following:

- dump list of dictionaries into a file in JSON format
- pass file's path as input parameter to the subprocess
- retrieve (load) list of dictionaries from file in the second script

However, dump and load are I/O operations which are very slow, especially with big files, thus I was wondering whether there is another way to share such list of dictionaries with the second script directly in memory.

Comment: you should definitely use an SQL database, which is considered as `thread-safe`

Comment: any reason you can't use threads instead?

Comment: @sashaboulouds I cannot use an SQL database because the second script computes further data to be inserted into those dictionaries and only after that I can populate the db with data in dictionaries. Besides this, databases are slow as well.

Comment: @Marat a lot of code and modules rely on such subprocess, so too much refactory would be needed.

Comment: Why do you use subprocess instead of multiprocessing?

Comment: The first script is running with Jython (mandatory for my needs), but there are some libraries needed which are not available for Jython, so I run a second script via subprocess so that CPython is used for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a communication link between the different programs/processes using a pipe. This will allow you to pass messages between them without writing to disc.

And, to make things even nicer, a pair of pipes already exists between a main process and its sub-processes, namely `stdin` and `stdout`. Thus, when starting your subprocess, make sure to re-route `stdin` to a pipe, and you will have a way to write directly to the sub-process: `subprocess.call([subprogram], stdin=subprocess.PIPE ...)`

Of course the sub-process/program must be able to handle the input over that link, instead of reading from disc. I think this is the cleanest and simplest way to achieve what you want, provided this works from Jython, which I have never tried.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you can't when using the subprocess module, but rewriting and restructuring using multiprocessing instead (if that is feasible) would allow you to use the options at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

However, be aware that due to locking overhead etc there is a high risk this will impact the performance, so it might be slower than copying the data. If you want to optimise the copying consider using pickle instead of json for serialisation.